# Adding ActiveAdmin to a RoR application using webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, activeadmin

Im trying to add ActiveAdmin to a (massive) application. I follow all the steps here:

https://activeadmin.info/0-installation.html#setting-up-active-admin

The installation process was fine. My problem here is with the assets. When I tried to run:

http://localhost:3000/admin/login/

I got an error:

```
Showing /Users/fmaymone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activeadmin- 
1.1.0/app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb where line #9 raised:

couldn't find file 'jquery3' with type 'application/javascript'
Checked in these paths:
```

This application is kind of tricky. Its running webpack together with the rails server. I never worked with this kind of configuration.

Theres not a application.js where I can add a require//

I tried doing a npm i jquery too.

Should I put directly inside the webpack the jquery.js?

This is my GemFile

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.2'

# This needs to be declared earlier than alphabetical order to load properly re: the app.
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.0.0'



gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.3'
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
gem 'active_model-errors_details'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'activerecord-rescue_from_duplicate'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'addressable'
gem 'ahoy_email'
gem 'ahoy_matey'
gem 'airbrake', '~>6.2'
gem 'ajax-datatables-rails'
gem 'asset_sync'
gem 'attachment_on_the_fly'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.0'
gem 'axlsx', '2.1.0.pre'
gem 'axlsx_rails'
gem 'blazer'
gem 'bootstrap-generators', '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.4'
gem 'browser-timezone-rails'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'countries'
gem 'daemons'
gem 'data_migrate', '~>5.0'
gem 'delayed_job', '~>4.1.5'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'devise'
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'double-bag-ftps'
gem 'faraday'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7.0'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.5.1'
gem 'hashdiff'
gem 'hashformer'
gem 'hashie'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'hubspot-ruby', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'jira-ruby'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: "rweng/jquery-datatables-rails", branch: "master"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'json-schema'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'libv8', '6.7.288.46.1'
gem 'mailgun-ruby', '~>1.1.6'
gem 'marketingcloudsdk', '~> 1.0'
gem 'mini_racer', '0.2.3', platforms: :ruby
gem 'mjml-rails'
gem 'money-rails', '~>1'
gem 'multipart-post'
gem 'net-scp'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'oj'
gem 'oj_mimic_json'
gem 'pg'
gem 'progress_bar'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'rails-observers', '~> 0.1.2'
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'react_on_rails', '~>6'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'retriable', '~> 3.1'
gem 'roo', '~> 2.7.0'
gem 'roo-xls'
gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.6'
gem 'savon', '~> 2.2.0'
gem 'schema_plus_pg_indexes'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'seed_dump'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'slither', :git => 'https://github.com/Programatica/slither.git'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 2.2.5'
gem 'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.2.5'# optional pre-packaged Solr distribution for use in development
gem 'taxjar-ruby', require: 'taxjar'
gem 'thin'
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 4.0'
gem 'wannabe_bool'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'wisper', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'wisper-rspec', require: false, groups: [:development, :test]
gem 'workflow'
gem "graphql"
gem "graphql-errors"
gem "graphql-batch"
gem "graphql-guard"
gem "nokogiri"

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'sprockets-redirect'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
  gem 'shoulda-callback-matchers', '~> 1.1.1'
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem "vcr"
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "pry"
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem "guard-rspec"
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'graphiql-rails'
  gem "puma"
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec_candy'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'to_factory'
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'test_after_commit', :group => :test
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

Thanks

Comment: This is one of the problems. I dont know where to check this in this kind of configuration app (webpack + rails server). Any lights?

Comment: open the gemfile.lock and search jquery-rails you'll find the version next to it.

Comment: jquery-rails (4.1.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)

Comment: In Gemfile you are using which version of rails? if < 4.2, try updating with 5.0 or so.

Comment: Rails 4.2.2. I dont think I can change the app to 5. Its a very old legacy app

Comment: So, it is recommended to use older version of activeadmin that works with version of code. Try using ruby toolbox to check the support.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an old version of *jquery-rails* which turn out to raise an error. jquery3 is required in the base javascript file, and the support for it was not available before the rails 4.2.0 version in *jquery-rails* gem. Therefore, I recommend you to check the versions of *jquery-rails* with rails and *activeadmin* gem.

Comment: Im using rails 4.2.2

Comment: Can you please paste your Gemfile here?

Comment: Sure. Editing the question

Comment: You have conflict with rails version as with jquery. Either upgrading rails or downgrade the activeadmin. Activeadmin 1.4.2 needs jquery-4.2.0.
You can check the compatibilities here. https://rubygems.org/gems/activeadmin/versions/1.4.0